# how to add headers to a numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy.ndarray having dimensions of 23411 x 3.
I would like to add headers to the top of the matrix called: "summary", "age", and "label". In that order.

In:

```
matrix.shape
```

Out:

```
(23411L, 3L)
```

In:

```
type(matrix)
```

Out:

```
numpy.ndarray
```

I tried using the numpy.recarray but it did not work. any suggestions??

Comment: how did you try recarray? I can construct a structured array, but the process isn't trivial. And result isn't just added headers.  What would you do with the array and headers?

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this with [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

```
import pandas as pd
matrix = [...] # your ndarray

matrix = pd.DataFrame(data=matrix, columns=["summary", "age", "label"])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can fiddle the dtype:

```
>>> a = np.arange(12).reshape(4, 3)
>>> 
>>> dt = a.dtype
>>> 
>>> ahead = a.view(np.dtype([('summary', dt), ('age', dt), ('label', dt)]))
>>> 
>>> ahead
array([[(0,  1,  2)],
       [(3,  4,  5)],
       [(6,  7,  8)],
       [(9, 10, 11)]],
      dtype=[('summary', '<i8'), ('age', '<i8'), ('label', '<i8')])
>>> ahead['summary']
array([[0],
       [3],
       [6],
       [9]])
```

But be warned that those composite dtype arrays are not very useful as far as I can tell:

```
>>> ahead @ ahead.T
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: invalid data type for einsum
```

to give just one example.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own class with members including the numpy array and the headings as strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to do this. Try matrix.dtype. This should give you something like dtype('int32'). Your headers would be strings.

As far as I know you can only store one datatype in a numpy array/matrix.

Comment: `a = np.asarray([2, 2.1, "2"], dtype = object)` Now test the type of each element.

Comment: @MrT Good point. This way you could force the 0th element to be a string with the name.